# Sustes in Solr running and using lots of CPU power

Tags: solr

I am trying to figure out what this process is:

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2398 solr      20   0  709920  16412   1364 S 771.5  0.0  19:39.02 sustes
```

I thought maybe it was from a script doing an optimization of the database - but I've disabled that and its still there even after a reboot. Seems excessively high!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr doesn't usually launch any external processes, and the Internet seems to [indicate your server has been compromised](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/what-is-this-sustes-in-my-process-in-my-cpu-stats) and [someone is running](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/bd00b4a2f7206de97458cd06c51de4496f714b8cc6494505670f9c5aa5b1d3b0?environmentId=300) a cryptominer binary on your server.

It's time to kill any access to the server, recreate the server and firewall it off from the world, find out how they got in and make sure it doesn't happen again.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Thats a PITA :( I've been telling him for months and months that his root password is too simple (basic word + a few digits), and that this would happen one day (not if, but when). I've checked the crons but can't see anything that shouldn't be there. Could they be doing it some other way?

Comment: There's many ways of hiding malware on servers, which is why reinstalling from a known good source usually is the only practical option. There's probably many different malwares using the same payload (`sustes` is what they're dropping to do crypto mining for them) - it might have gotten on the server manually for all we can tell. A proper examination of logs and which files got dropped where and when can tell you more, but that's usually a task for a forensic team.

Comment: ah rubbish, thats gonna be a real mission to rebuild the server from scratch :( (lots of stuff like solr, perl modules etc). I'll talk to the guy whose server it is and see what he wants to do. I just wish people would take my advise about secure passwords for their servers and not just go for "ease of remembering" :/

Comment: Nothing to do. That cryptominner modify some libs of the kernel. Highly probable not easy to remove. Just disconnect, format and reinstall but change your security protocols.

Answer (score 0):

It shows some external process is running - Maybe CryptoJacking which is Bigger than Ransomware, It's a new money maker.

Please check below files for any unwanted logs and any connection to external URL's
1. var/log/syslog and
2. Or if you are using window/Linux machines - check window service/process(Window) or any cron job(Linux).

Comment: Yeah it was. There was a backdoor on Solr (via the config API update tool, that allowed you to run commands!). They then had a cron on the "solr" user. We cleaned it up, updated Solr, and then disabled the solr users cron (so they couldn't set it up again). Was a total PITA but I think we got it.

Comment: That’s good, I would suggest to keep an eye on logs it may be a slow warm, in that case you may need to setup new infra.